# How to bring my first column to my automate email in App Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Some weeks ago I developed a code that takes some information from a spreadsheet each time a user submit a form, and then, send me an email with the information completed. It works really well.
However, I am intending to add a Ticket number in the first column of the sheet (without adding it in the google form) but it is not being recognized by my code.

[image: the spreadsheet]

Do you have any clue about how could I add this first column to my email each time I receive a new submit?
I attach my code.

```js
function formSubmitReply(e) {

  // VARIABLES   
    var ticketNo;         
    var alUser = e.values[1];
    var country = e.values[3];
    var language = e.values[2];
    var category = e.values[4];
    var title = e.values[5];
    var questions = e.values[6];
    var attach = e.values[7];
    var entityEn = e.values[8];
    var categoryEn = e.values[9];
    var titleEn = e.values[10];
    var questionsEn = e.values[11];
    var attachEn = e.values[12];
    

    var userEmail = "nam.hr@airliquide.com";  

    var msgFr =  
  // Add table style and format the cells with th and tr 
  "<table border='1' border-radius='5px' style='border-collapse:collapse; font-family:sans-serif;'>" +
    "<tr>" +
      "<th>Employé AL</th>" +      
      "<th>Sélection du pays</th>" +
      "<th>Langue préférée</th>" +
      "<th>Catégorie</th>" +
      "<th>Sujet</th>" +
      "<th>Contenu de la demande</th>" +
      "<th>Pièce jointe</th>" +
      "<th>#</th>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "<tr>" +
      "<td>" + alUser + "</td>" +      
      "<td>" + country + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + language + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + category + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + title + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + questions + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + attach + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + ticketNo + "</td>" +
    "</tr>" +
  "</table>";      

var msgEn = 
  
  // Add table style and format the cells with th and tr 
  "<table border='1' style='border-collapse:collapse; font-family:sans-serif;'>" +
    "<tr>" +
      "<th>AL user</th>" +      
      "<th>Country</th>" +
      "<th>Preferred Language</th>" +
      "<th>Category</th>" +
      "<th>Title</th>" +
      "<th>Question</th>" +
      "<th>Attachments</th>" +
      "<th>#</th>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "<tr>" +
      "<td>" + alUser + "</td>" +      
      "<td>" + entityEn + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + language + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + categoryEn + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + titleEn + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + questionsEn + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + attachEn + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + ticketNo + "</td>" +
    "</tr>" +
  "</table>";        
    
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: userEmail,
      subject: 'NAM HR Mailbox | ' + categoryEn + category,
      htmlBody: (language=="English") ? msgEn : msgFr,
      name: alUser, 
      replyTo: alUser
    });
}
```

[image: email]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You need to add the first column manually in the spreadsheet then add this code to fill up the values every form submit:

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var id = e.range.getRow();
  var startNum = 850; // to start the entries from T0850
  var control = startNum + id - 2;
  var ticketNo = "T"+control.toString().padStart(4,"0");
  ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(id,1).setValue(ticketNo);

  // VARIABLES
    var alUser = e.values[1];
    var country = e.values[3];
    .....
```

The rest of the code should be the same as with your question.

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi! it's working really well, thank you very much! I only deleted the control variable and start number as I could get the same ID  as the row number

Comment: Much appreciated! :)